# RenderAction from another controller in AttributeRouting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm using AttributeRouting extension with Asp.Net Mvc 4 RC. It is ok for calling RenderAction from same controller. But when I called it from another controller's view I got "No route in the route table matches the supplied values" exception.

PS:I've tested Asp.Net MVC 4 RC without AttributeRouting. Everything is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related with "AREA". You could not call RenderAction from another area, you have to add :

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Message", new { area = "" });}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have replaced all general routes with your own custom routes in Global.asax.
Can you please put the general route (`{controller}/{action}`) back into the file?   It should work.

If that doesn't work then you may have to provide
`[ChildActionOnly]` attribute in your action.

Comment: There is both ChildActionOnlyAttribute on Action  and PartialViewResult as return parameter. http://www.make-awesome.com/2012/07/perfectionist-routing-in-asp-net-mvc/ I've implemented using this suggestion. General route did not solve my problem also.